# where to create folder

Tags: java, jsp, maven, directory

I am working on jsp,I am using a book where there is a code to access image from the folder.The code is like this

```
<jsp:useBean id="cartoon" class="com.ora.jsp.beans.motd.CartoonBean" />
<img src="images/<jsp:getProperty name="cartoon" property="fileName" />">
```

So I dont know where to create the "images" folder,I mean whether inside webapp or WEB-INF.I am using maven.so below is my Project structure.
[image]

so can anyone tell me where should I create folder

Comment: I'd create the `images` folder next to `WEB-INF`, since the images would need to be publicly accessible in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Side-to-side with WEB-INF. The content under WEB-INF is not delivered to the browser. It is (should be) non-public data. Place sensitive data there.

Hence `http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF/web.xml` does not work.

Access to JSP inside WEB-INF works with the url-mappings, using web.xml or the newer annotations.

Comment: -1 The contents of `/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/resources` are delivered since 2.5. I know its stupid, but enables you to have .jsp in a .jar.

Comment: @PeterRader good point, for mentioning the exception. I did not, as `WEB-INF/classes` is mostly generated. For others: that are meta data about the web application.

Comment: even the `/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar!/META-INF/resources/` can be delivered. It can kill every dependency-management.

Answer (score 1):

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html sais in: `/src/main/webapp/` (need 5 characters more before post my answer)

Comment: really I did not understand what you said "need 5 characters more before post my answer".

Comment: the website `stackoverflow.com` dont let me post answers who has less than 25 characters. So i must have a test-text who is unfortunatelly part of the answer itself.